# SAPUI5 Removing custom item in List

Tags: sapui5

i'm new in sapui5. I provide custom list items to my List component

```
<List items="{data>/Stages}">
   <CustomListItem>
       <control:TechCardStage value="{data>}" 
         remove="onStageRemove" />
   </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Where `control:TechCardStage` is my custom control. There is a class variable `this.bIsOpened` in this control. My problem: i have 2 list items, 1 with `this.bIsOpened === true`, 2 with `this.bIsOpened === false`, how can i remove correctly the second one item? I tried fire event (remove) and in my subscribe function i do this:

```
onStageRemove: function(oEvent) {
                var oValue = oEvent.getParameter('value');
                this.setModelProperty(
                    'data',
                    '/Stages',
                    this.getView()
                        .getModel('data')
                        .getData()
                        .Stages.filter(function(oStage) {
                            return oStage.Id !== oValue.Id;
                        }),
                );
            },
```

It removes the item, but `this.bIsOpened` will be true, although it was false.

Comment: Maybe we need more information about the custom control. Also it's still unclear for me what your goal is you want to achieve. Do you want to remove some data out of the binding/model?

Comment: Actualy i found a way to solve my problem but i will try to describe it more clearly.
1) I have a parent controller where i have a model `data`. In this model i have an array of objects `Stages`. So i a have a List which is built by this `array` (you can see it by my first "code example" (xml)).
2) In this list i use a custome control. This custome control contain Panel element which can be expanded and this "expanded state" depends on class variable `this.bIsOpened`.
3) I can edit my list. So i needed a feature to delete my items and save it if i need.

Comment: I thought that i can reach this from firing an event `remove` which i defined (this event is fired when user click on remove button (each my list item contain this button)) and by removing a specific element `Stage` from my model (code exmaple 2). But i had a scenario where my first element panel was  opened (`this.bIsOpened === true`) and second was closed (`this.bIsOpened === false`). After removing first item i had only the second one but it was opened (`this.bIsOpened === true`) (it seems like `this` in my item was another (from my removed element)).

Comment: Today i tried a way to remove not basically an element from model but list item from my List. And for now it seems pretty nice to me.
`onStageRemove: function(oEvent) {
     var oValue = oEvent.getParameter('value');
     this.getView()
       .byId('stageList')
       .removeItem(oValue);
},`

Comment: Actually i have another issue, i can "Cancel" my changes by pressing a specific button. So when i remove my item from list and try to prevent my changes my list doesn't update to back. I try this:
```onCancel: function() {
                this.getView().setModel('data', this._initialTechCard)},```
this._initialTechCard exactly contains all data before i removed it in my List.